# Split EDMX for Entity Framework - Breakout object layer into separate files - possible?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to break out the partial classes in a split edmx's objectlayer.cs into a file per class?

Thanks

Comment: Do you intend on being able to update the model after splitting out the classes?

Comment: Not automatically no.

We already have it in the split format (.msl, .ssl, .csdl and .objectlayer.cs) so we're doing things manually, but yes we would want to alter the partials at a later date, but have no trouble doing it manually.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In this scenario, do you still get compile-time error-checking?  How does the compiler know what classes are going to be generated (and then extended by your partial classes) if there is no .edmx file?

Comment: Yes, in the original split format (msl, ssdl, csdl and objectlayer) you still get compile time error checking, or you can validate them from a dos prompt -

Comment: "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\edmgen.exe" /mode:ValidateArtifacts /inssdl:.\database.ssdl /inmsl:.\database.msl /incsdl:.\database.csdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the answers so far seem to be discussing splitting the EDMX into it's parts. It sounds from your question that you want to break out the generated classes into separate files. This is not currently supported, but you may be able to do it using the T4 templates with EF in 4.0. You can already do this using Damien Guard's L2ST4 templates for LINQ to SQL.

Jim Wooley

www.ThinqLinq.com