# Entity Framework - separate class files

Tags: entity-framework, class

I am playing around with the latest Entity Framework, and I would like to separate the generated classes into 1 file per class if possible.

I also want to be able to re-generate these files after splitting.

Although this question asks the question, it is old and the accepted answer is "maybe in the future." [Split EDMX for Entity Framework - Breakout object layer into separate files - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340673/split-edmx-for-entity-framework-breakout-object-layer-into-separate-files-pos)

Is it possible to do this? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there are T4 templates out there that do this, likely multiple variants, but I haven't looked recently.

Comment: You're right, it is bundled with this (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313). Seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EFv4 and T4 template (for entity objects or POCOs). It will create separate file for each created entity. I'm not sure why you want it. It is generated code which mustn't be manually modified because modifications will be lost during next regenerating.

Breaking EDMX insto separate files is somehow possible but pretty hard - it is manual work. Check these articles ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/04/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-1.aspx) and [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/02/11/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-2.aspx)). It is approach for working with large models.

Comment: Yeah I would prefer the T4 template method I think it would be unwise to try and split the EDMX file - that could be hard to maintain. Thanks For the links!

Comment: I found a link from MSDN (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) which is a POCO entity generator. Thanks :)

Comment: The link above is actually a T4 template.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Developer for SQL Server](http://devart.com/entitydeveloper/) provides some [enhancements for large EF models handling](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/large-models.html), like multiple diagrams. As for the code generation, there is a File Per Class code generation option as well.

Answer (score -5):

Forget the generation crap and start with the latest EF and use the code first approach. You then have complete control over the POCO. I am still a bit underwhelmed on EF, but the code first approach will allow you to create the classes as you like and then link them in to ORM bits. If you don't want to write your own classes, I know of no way to achieve what you desire.

Comment: The "code first" approach is not a choice that I have to make, as part of methodologies I am working with the database design comes first. I do not base my technology strategies on how under/overwhelmed I am by them, but how they will add value to my project.

Comment: A request can be made to Microsoft for single class per file, but it will not appear for quite some time, as the next reelease is already feature set. They will evaluate if it is a big enough need to fit in the 80% and do it if so. The other option is third party tools or heading to code first.

Comment: In the VS gallery (see link above), Microsoft have already released functionality to do this.  Although it is not bundled by default with VS 2010.